# How to get third-party API up-to-date?

Tags: api

So, I stepped once at this problem. I had offered a website that used the SoundCloud API. Everything worked properly. Content was extracted from the JSON and placed in the layout of the website. However, I received an email one day from the owner of the website, which indicated that the website did not work properly. I then came out to investigate and came to the conclusion that the "problem" was not on my side, but at SoundCloud's side. I studied on the API page of SoundCloud and came to the conclusion that the API had received a major update, making the link with SC and the site no longer worked.

Lately I'm trying many new APIs to, including those from Instagram and Dribbble. I was therefore wondering if it is at all possible to ensure that such problems can be reduced in the future or it might be appropriate API pages of this third-party APIs to monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "right" answer.  After many years of using and maintaining many APIs here are some of the conclusions I've come to:

- The best providers let you work with a specific version of their API whose interface and expected behavior never changes.  They might release bug fixes and new endpoints, but you can be confident that as long as the API is supported it will not break your system.
- A good provider will provide an end-of-life date for each version of their API.  It's up to you to keep track of when you need to update.
- Paid services will often be supported longer than free services. Plus the contract / SLA will guarantee it remains available for a specific amount of time.

The most popular APIs often have mailing lists and/or blogs.  For those that offer it, sign up to be notified of updates.  For those that don't you'll have to monitor their blogs or news posts.  And I suggest not using any service that would drop support for an API version without warning.